# ASP.NET quick contact form not working

Tags: asp.net, contact-form

I am having a Quick contact form on an aspx page which is not working I am using a try/catch block in case of an exception well till now only the catch is working.Please help me with the code I am using the mail message class of the System.Net.Mail namespace.Her's the code

```
try
{
    MailMessage EmailMsg = new MailMessage();
    EmailMsg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text,txtName.Text);
    EmailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress("mail address"));
    EmailMsg.Subject = "WebAssist Email form";
    EmailMsg.Body = "<html><body>This is a text<hr>Test test</body></html>";
    EmailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    EmailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
    SmtpClient MailClient = new SmtpClient("");
    MailClient.EnableSsl = true;
    MailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("","");
    MailClient.Send(EmailMsg);
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "Email sent";
}
catch
{
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "Your email was not sent";
}
```

Please tell what to write in the smtp constructor,in the network credentials
Thank you in advance

Comment: What error are you getting that causes you to go into the catch block?  And where is your mail server located - that information seems to be missing?

Comment: You probably don't want to just ignore all exceptions like that.  Exceptions tend to contain useful information about errors that occur.

Comment: I am having the IP address of my mail server I forgot to write here I needed to know what to write in the credentials thing and is there any statement missing

Comment: Hey! how can i test this email thing on my development interface.i WAS ALWAYS TESTING IT live

Comment: @Roadrunner: All you need is a running instance of an SMTP service.  Whether its on your development machine, in some other shared location on your network, a public service like GMail, etc. doesn't really matter.  You just need an SMTP service that you can connect to and send emails.  If you need to install one locally, there are tons of free SMTP servers out there.

Answer (score 2):

**Take the catch statement out** - you want to let the exception propagate up the call stack so that you can find out what the problem is.  All you're doing now is hiding it.

Once you've solved the problem I suggest you take a look at [exception handling best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx).

Comment: How can i test it on my local server.doen't it needs some internet thing

Comment: @Roadrunner: If your local server has an SMTP service running on it, you can test it by connecting to that.  ("localhost" and "25" are likely the values you want.)

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class can be called in one of three ways:

1. SmtpClient() - Initializes a new instance of the SmtpClient class by using configuration file settings.
2. SmtpClient(String) - Initializes a new instance of the SmtpClient class that sends e-mail by using the specified SMTP server.
3. SmtpClient(String, Int32) - Initializes a new instance of the SmtpClient class that sends e-mail by using the specified SMTP server and port.

As for what actual values need to be supplied, that's really between you and your SMTP server.  We can't help you there.  The string will be the name of the server (possibly even just its IP address) and the port will most likely be 25, but could be anything.